# Why is my phone detecting two taps instead of one on the screen?

Tags: touchscreen, sony-xperia-z3

I'm observing a strange behaviour on my phone out of the blue. Yesterday, the left side of my screen stopped working properly. I started having a hard time clicking anything next to the left edge, typing the keyboard or pressing buttons on the left.

I enabled *Developer Options > Input > Show touches*, and I was able to observe that when I try to tap the left side of the screen, the screen appears to detect two taps on opposing sides of a column, as if the whole column of pixels were damaged. The phone hasn't suffered any hits or gotten wet. This is just out of nowhere.

[image: IMG:]

I've uploaded a video of this to make it clearer [here](https://youtu.be/esXL2sjUexw).

This is an Xperia Z3, D6603, running Android 5.1.1.

Has anyone encountered something like this? I've tried restarting the phone to no avail.

Comment: Do you have any gesture apps installed? Sometimes they are even native to the particular phone? Maybe the allowable trigger real estate is defined especially broad? Multi-app/multi-screen enabled?

Comment: Hi @wbogacz, I don't have any gesture apps installed. But if that were the case, wouldn't that affect the entire screen? If you look at the video you'll see it happens all along a vertical area alongside left edge of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hardware problem. The screen sensor is faulty. The actions most likely to solve the problem:

1. Factory reset
2. Cleaning of the screen ribbon cable
3. Replacement of the screen.

Comment: can you please explain how to clean the screen ribbon cable? Can you point me to a video or article somewhere that explains this? Also, how does a factory reset solve a hardware problem?

Comment: In the end I had to take it to a technical service shop where they replaced the screen. Unfortunately on this model that also means replacing the entire frame because the screen and frame are one.

Comment: Sony official support is very bad in this regard BTW. They basically refuse to even try to fix a device that's past warranty. So if you face this problem take it to a good third party. They'll replace the screen using spares from other scratched devices but it's your best shot. The reason for the "double touch" symptom is that when a pixel goes out, the entire column goes with it. I guess it's a design issue. They told me humidity might have caused it.

Answer (score 0):

It some time happens when some of the apps in the background are going through connection or network problems and they are third party they start behaving badly and they start making your phone to hang and make waste touches

Comment: I've killed/dismissed every app and restarted twice, but still observe this. Any idea on how to solve it?